# How to implement this script on a Mac

Tags: terminal, script, perl

I just read [Matt Might's blog](http://matt.might.net/) post on [eliminating filler and "weasels"](http://matt.might.net/articles/shell-scripts-for-passive-voice-weasel-words-duplicates/) from my writing, and I am wondering how I would implement this on Latex to run and check my document? I know I should use terminal, but I'm not at all familiar with how Terminal accepts commands or which directory I would store the script in?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is "Latex"?

Comment: LaTeX is a typesetting system: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/latex/info

Answer (score 4):

You could save the script as `~/Scripts/weasels.sh` with any text editor, and run it with `bash ~/Scripts/weasels.sh ~/Documents/input\ file.txt`. Or if you use [TextMate](http://macromates.com), you can run the script with just ⌘R.

If you want to run the script with `weasels` instead of `bash ~/Scripts/weasels.sh`, you can make it executable and add its folder to the path:

```
mv ~/Scripts/weasels.sh ~/Scripts/weasels
chmod +x ~/Scripts/weasels
echo 'export PATH=~/Scripts:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
. ~/.bash_profile
weasels ~/Documents/input\ file.txt
```

Comment: Hi Lauri, thanks for your help! I've created a perl file (weasels.pl) in TextMate with the three scripts from Matt's blog. Should I actually save it as "weasels.sh"? And would I run it after typing up my LaTeX document, where the foo.tex would go in place of "file.txt"? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should save them in separate files. And the first two scripts are shell scripts, which are commonly saved with a .sh extension (or no extension if they are executable). And yeah, it should also work with .tex files. It's probably better to start out with learning Python (look at the [Google Trends graphs](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?hl=en#q=python%20tutorial%2C%20ruby%20tutorial%2C%20perl%20tutorial%2C%20bash%20tutorial&cmpt=q) for Python vs Perl vs Ruby).